# How to accept JSON and XML both in Web API post method

Tags: json, .net, xml, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Patient/$gpc.registerstudent")]       
    [SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Register student")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registerstudent([FromBody] JObject parameters,[FromBody] xElement Param )
    {
    }
```

Nothing worked.
I am using ASP .NET Web API. And my requirement is that should be able to post me XML as well as JSON requests.currently am able to request only json request

xml example:

Comment: "Nothing worked" what did you try? Did you use `AddXmlSerializerFormatters`

Comment: i have added in startup.cs services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters() tried but not worked

Comment: Also `[FromBody] JObject parameters` what do you expect to happen here? You would have to pass a JObject inside XML? And you can't have two `FromBody` parameters anyway. Perhaps you should just have a single `[FromBody] dynamic parameters` although to be honest it's not clear why you don't have explicit paramaters rather than some big dynamic blob.

Comment: Student/$gpc.registerstudent?_format=application%2Ffhir%2Bxml this my RequestUri now am getting Bad Request for XML Post json is working fine.

Comment: That's not how you pass a format option. You need to pass it in the `Accept` header.

Comment: I am not sure why `Nothing worked`, But the solution is add `AddXmlSerializerFormatters` in your configuration.

Comment: added all configuration still am getting bad request for XML Request Body

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support multiple de-serializers for the same controller endpoint, then you should not try to accept a generic content like `JObject` or `xElement` as the argument for your controller. The other *Faux Pas* is that your method can only have a single argument decorated with the `FromBodyAttribute`.

Configuring `services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters()`  is all you need to support automatic deserialization from XML and Serialization to XML via a mechanims called *content negotiation*. For this to work as an input type, you must first use a *typed* argument in your method, then the `FromBodyAttribute` will use the configured *SerializerFormatters* to deserialize the *body* to the requested type based on the *Content-Type* of the request.

> One caveat that I have found is that you should use the `application/xml` as the `Content-Type` for posting and XML document.

We use the `Consumes` attribute to declare the supported *input* content types,  the `Produces` attribute describes the response types that are supported.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Patient/$gpc.registerstudent")]       
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Register student")]
[Consumes("application/xml", "application/json")]
[Produces("application/xml", "application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Registerstudent([FromBody] RegisterStudentRequestDTO request)
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    return Ok(request); // just echo out for now to show the output serialization
}
```

In this case my register DTO is very simple:

```
public class RegisterStudentRequestDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set;}
}
```

The way that a caller can define the expected response type if by providing an `Accept` header. For instance, we can now provide a XML input to this method and tell the controller to serialize the response into XML:

> In the request, `Content-Type` header describes the input that we are providing, the `Accept` header describes the content-type of the response.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:7208/WeatherForecast/Patient/$gpc.registerstudent' \
  -H 'accept: application/xml' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RegisterStudentRequestDTO>
    <Name>string</Name>
    <Date>2023-07-04T12:34:43.128Z</Date>
    <Comments>string</Comments>
</RegisterStudentRequestDTO>'
```

*You will notice that the name of the elements MUST match the casing of the name of the class and properties, by default the XML serializer **is** case-sensitive.*

This will return:

```
<RegisterStudentRequestDTO xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Name>string</Name>
    <Date>2023-07-04T12:34:43.128Z</Date>
    <Comments>string</Comments>
</RegisterStudentRequestDTO>
```

But if you change the `Accept` header to `application/json` then without altering any code, the output changes to this:

```
{
    "name": "string",
    "date": "2023-07-04T12:29:14.595Z",
    "comments": "string"
}
```

To complete the demo, to provide JSON input, the request would look like this:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:7208/WeatherForecast/Patient/$gpc.registerstudent' \
  -H 'accept: application/xml' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "name":"string", "date":"2023-07-04T12:29:14.595Z" , "comments": "string" }'
```

The response will still be in `application/xml` due to the `Accept` header.

Further Reading:

- [Input Formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#input-formatters-2)
- [Posting an XML to WebAPI and return a result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26671830/1690217)
- [How to pass xml input (request) to Web api on .net core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61586041/1690217)

You can also read about a workaround here: [Issue receiveing POST request with Content-Type text/xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/436849/issue-receiveing-post-request-with-content-type-te)

---

If you receive a response similar to this:

```
<problem xmlns="urn:ietf:rfc:7807">
    <status>400</status>
    <title>One or more validation errors occurred.</title>
    <type>https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1</type>
    <traceId>00-94549daf9ab55604a516f0b2b012d563-23030c613b93e726-00</traceId>
    <MVC-Errors>
        <MVC-Empty>An error occurred while deserializing input data.</MVC-Empty>
        <request>The request field is required.</request>
    </MVC-Errors>
</problem>
```

Then please check the casing of your class or property names, the swagger document will use (lower) camel case by default in the *Try it Now* section, this is unfortunate:

[image: try it now example]

Providing the correctly typed input will work, you can also implement `DataContractAttribute` and `DataMemberAttribute` to explicitly rename the properties to their lower case variant. If you do this, you will need to also add the `.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()` to your fluent `AddControllers()` implementation in `startup.cs`/`program.cs`

Comment: hi Need More Information on above

Comment: after making above changes also getting An error occurred while deserializing input data.The request field is required.

Comment: I tried to explain that at the end, if you get "Field is required" then this probably means your casing does not match _exactly_ with the class and property names. You should update your post with the _exact_ class definition and the body content that you are sending.

Comment: thanks normal content type is working fine.how to post fhir+xml to web api?

Comment: It should work fine as long as the input deserializes into your DTO class correctly. The error indicates that there is an issue with the structure of your class. You would be better off using JSON output instead of fhir+xml if you can, otherwise you should edit your post with an example input and your DTO class (as I asked earlier) then I can show you specifically where the issue is.

Comment: hi @Chris Schaller Thanks for your input. from consumer we are getting xml and json we are just posting same to web api we are unable to post xml as input.

Comment: in api we input [FromBody] xElement then its working fine and json failing...we need to accept both xml and json.

Comment: how to post both xml and json to Endpoint.we have tried dynamic,string not working

Comment: The solution that I have presented, where you use a _DTO_ and `AddXmlSerializerFormatters`  is how you support both types of inputs with a single method. Using `xElement` or `JObject` will restrict it to XML or JSON generic input (untyped) but not both. Your problem appears to be in your DTO definition, but since you have not posted the raw input or a typed class to deserialize the response to, it is hard to give you a specific answer to your current issue.